# Appwarp maven plugin

Tags: java, maven-3, appwarp

**What is the maven plugin for App Warp,**
Actually I tried some old dependencies,

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.shephertz.app42.gaming</groupId>
<artifactId>multiplayer-client</artifactId>
<version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But It didn't work
Can Anybody Help me?
Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 0):

Shephertz provides java sdk for AppWarp in JAR format and is only available through their download site. It is not available in MVN Repositories.

However you can download .jar file for AppWarp and add in your local MVN repo for using it in your Maven project.

A simple example of installing AppWarp jar in local maven repo is as follows :

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=multiplayer-client-1.5.2.jar -DgroupId=com.shephertz.app42.gaming -DartifactId=multiplayer-client -Dversion=1.5.2 -Dpackaging=jar
```